# FB App Messenger Browser Issue : How to close popup window and redirect the parent window

Tags: javascript, php, ios, facebook, popupwindow

Why this code is not working in FB App Messenger Browser (Webview).
Parent Window:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script language="Javascript">

        function showFBWindow(){
            url = "allowfbchild.html"
            newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
            if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" OnClick="showFBWindow()" value="Open FB" />

</body>
</html>
```

Child Window(allowfbchild.html) :

```
<html>
<head>

    <script language="Javascript">

        function redirectToFB(){
            window.opener.location.href="http://wwww.facebook.com";
            self.close();
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    Allow the user to view FB
    <br/>Are you sure?
    <input type="button" value="Ok" OnClick="redirectToFB()" />

</body>
</html>
```

When clicking on redirectToFB() button. Its not working as per coded.

Comment: Facebook’s in-app browser has quite a lot of restrictions on functionality. What exactly is not working here, at which point does it go wrong? What are you trying to achieve here in the first place, some kind of (primitive) confirmation before the user visits a link?

Comment: Problem is when i clicking on button in allowfbchild.html , opened popup should be closed and redirect parent window to http://wwww.facebook.com

Comment: @PhoolChandPareta Facing the same issue.. Got any solution for this????